# Does AdventureWorks db have tutorials / exercises?

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I downloaded and installed AdventureWorks db for sql server 2008.

Are there any exercises or tutorials for it?

I'd like to to practice SQL select statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [list of SQL Server Tutorials (*retired*)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms167593) for SQL Server 2008:

> - **Management Tutorials**
>
>   - [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb934498%28v%3dsql.105%29)
>   - [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms170207%28v%3dsql.105%29)
>   - [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms166575%28v%3dsql.105%29)
>   - [Administering Servers by Using Policy-Based Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb522659%28v%3dsql.105%29)
>   - [Evaluating Best Practices Using Policy-Based Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ee342165%28v%3dsql.105%29)
> - **Database Engine tutorials**
>
>   - [Getting Started with the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms345318%28v%3dsql.105%29)
>   - [Writing Transact-SQL Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms365303%28v%3dsql.105%29)
>   - [Using the hierarchyid Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb677213%28v%3dsql.105%29)

Comment: I corrected the link,  @John,  It really feels good the get dinged for making a typo.

Comment: hey joe i am also in san diego by the way, in university city

Comment: I sure will,  we better stop with the idle chatter,  I do not want to get dinged again by certain people.

Answer (score -1):

Read the views, stored procedures, and functions in the database. I don't believe there are any tutorials beyond that.

What's available is at http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/